# event.target in ui slider jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I `console.log(event)` in ui slider. Its gave me an object.

which has many properties. One of the properties is `target`.

When I see it on `console` it has a `+` symbol with it. Means it contains more than one properties.

[image]

as we can see it has `+` symbol. what does that mean, Is `target` hold an object or is it an array?

Because I `console.log(event.target)` its give me `htmlElement`. and when I `console.log(event.target.children)` its give me `object` that contains it children.

[image]

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: I just want to know. Is target is an object or array

Answer (score 1):

A quick test with jQuery slider is given me blow result..
and its clearly shows that ..

**`event`**  Is a jQuery Object

**`event.target`**  Is a Document Object Model(DOM)

[image]

Comment: window["ev"].target return htmlElement. But when you use window["ev"].target.children its return array. I have to assign a value in array or object in same way. How can I do that

Comment: var event={"target":"<div>adfasdf</div>","children":[1,2,3]}. How can I get the same result by using this object. Like if I use event.target.children which jquery object it will return array list.

Comment: can you post ur js fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will get the understanding that you are looking for to go deeper into your question from [MDN HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). This should clear up what you are wondering and give you the next steps to work with.